# Passing Data from Django View to Angular

Tags: django, python-2.7, angular, templates, view

Is this possible without using a REST API? I have a context in my Django view in which I place a variable after making a call to the database and this needs to percolate to my Angular front-end. Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in you view you can return [jsonresponse-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

# some your code ...
    return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})
```

Comment: But then this is similar to using a REST API. Is there another way to pass data from a Django view to an AngularJS front-end. Essentially, my application is an SPA with partials that are injected by AngularJS depending on the URL accessed (using an AngularJS router). The partials contain dynamic data (e.g. query results returned by Django from a database call).